# Read-only access to cached data from multiple Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Running on a 8-core 64G EC2 instance, I have a Java application whose main thread caches some dozends of gigabyte of data in a Hashmap. When the caching is done, 16 worker threads are spawned (being subclasses of Thread). They receive a reference to the Hashmap. The worker threads just read the cached data, they never ever modify it. I'd expect that all worker threads see the same cached data. This isn't however the case. It turns out that the data in the Hashmap has holes. For some keys the worker thread sees no values. This happens always for the same keys! When I spawn just 1 worker thread, all is fine however. Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: Are you saying the hashmap is modified only prior to the threads that access it being created?

Comment: How is your dozens-of-gigabyte map being generated? Is it a single thread, is it read from disk?

Comment: Yes, the hashmap is modified only prior to creating the worker threads. The hashmap is created from disk in a single (main) thread. To be more precise the hashmap's values are objects, and the cached data is stored in THashMap's private to these objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can go wrong while passing references around threads. Here's a checklist:

- Has the HashMap been completely initialized before the worker threads are created?
- Are you using a synchronized block to pass the reference to the hashmap if the threads have been created before the hashmap is completely written to?
- Alternatively, can you use a ConcurrentHashMap? This is optimized for reading(and writing) from multiple threads safely.
- To change the hashmap after the worker threads have started, ensure that you change the hashmap in a synchronized block, and the worker threads read the map in a synchonized block on the same object as the first synchronized (This is inefficient, and there are better ways to do it, based on your usage).

For the complete rundown on thread safety, you should go through the Java Memory Model or Java Concurrency In Practice book.

Comment: Yes, the HashMap is completely initialized before the worker threads are created. I also tried to declare the HashMap as volatile to make sure each CPU core gets the entire data, but to no avail.